# Why WiFi drivers carry firmware with them?

Tags: linux, graphics-card, linux-kernel, firmware, wifi-driver

Why do linux kernel modules for wireless LANs have 'device firmware'accompanying them while other driver modules don't seem to carry a copy of the firmware with them?

Edit: I've been informed that the same is the case with graphics card driver modules too.

Comment: Note that about half the firmwares in `linux-firmware` are actually for graphics cards...

Comment: Since I don't have any system with a separate graphics card, I was unaware about graphics firmwares. I'll edit my question accordingly.

Comment: It doesn't need to be separate – many Intel CPUs have a fully-featured GPU with loadable firmware.

Comment: Read here, https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Kernel/Firmware

Comment: @MariusMatutiae Thanks for the link. This leads to a large set of 'next' questions that I need to be answered. I'll post them when i can be sure they're formed well.